# Is it wrong to access TreeViewItems in WPF’s TreeView?

Tags: wpf, treeview

I’ve been having issues with the `TreeView` in WPF. This control makes it [very hard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616948/how-to-get-treeviewitem-from-hierarchicaldatatemplate-item) to access the `TreeViewItem`s it’s showing.

On several occasions I have worked around the need to access a `TreeViewItem`, for example I’ve accepted the fact that I’m [not supposed to access a node’s parent via TreeView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9761336/whats-the-wpf-way-to-mark-a-command-as-unavailable-only-if-the-parent-of-a-tree) (and am supposed to instead keep track of the parent myself). I’ve been doing this for two reasons: first, it’s obviously extremely hard to get at the `TreeViewItem`s, and secondly, I’ve been told that it’s hard because [I’m not supposed to need them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616948/how-to-get-treeviewitem-from-hierarchicaldatatemplate-item#comment12419945_616948) if I do things right.

However, this time I really see no way around this.

Basically, all I want is, given one of my viewmodel instances, scroll the tree view to it. [This is trivial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598110.aspx) if I could just get the corresponding `TreeViewItem`.

Am I doing things wrong again by trying to get at the `TreeViewItem`, or would that be the right approach?

Comment: [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28959/Introduction-to-Attached-Behaviors-in-WPF) is an artical by Josh Smith that deals with exactly what you want - scrolling treeview items into view. Josh's solution uses attached behaviours.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Simplifying the WPF TreeView by Using the ViewModel Pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode/) article by Josh Smith. I hope it helps.

Comment: This article is very good but doesn't explain how to use the SelectedItem or IsSelected property.

Answer (score 1):

Admittedly this is not straightforward but you can probably still do this while keeping a separation which does not require you to access the `TreeViewItems` knowingly. The essence in WPF is binding as already [noted by Kent Boogaart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9761780/546730) in your other question, here however you need to somehow deal with events. Your view-model needs to fire a `BringIntoView` event of its own while the view needs to react.

The easiest method might be to add a `EventSetter` on `Loaded` to make the `TreeViewItems` subscribe to said event on their `DataContext` which should be your view-model (if it isn't you can wait for `DataContextChanged`).

Comment: Sounds like this might be what I need. Thank you.

Comment: It’s real hard to accept the fact that the WPF approach is to re-expose manually in every view-model everything that’s already exposed by `TreeViewItem`. I get the idea though.

Comment: @romkyns: You will get used to it, also the mapping is not necessarily 1:1, as in theory you could have different views, e.g. if you represent one node's children in a simple ListBox, the event would be the same but it would affect another control. Reexposing just what you need gives you more flexibility and decouples the state from the current view.

Answer (score 0):

No, I dont see in what way accessing the items of a treeview is wrong.

I think the difficulties you are encountering are because you aren't seeing the treeview as it should be.

A leaf has a parent, but no children. 
A node can have a parent, and can have children. 
A node without a parent is a root.

Based on these principles ([SourceMaking `Composite pattern`](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/composite)) you should be able to do whatever you want using recursivity. (in both XAML and code)

Comment: The difficulty I am encountering is not in the understanding of trees; it’s in the API. The difficulty is **how**, given an item from my bound collection, can I get the corresponding `TreeViewItem`.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve come to the conclusion that it can’t be altogether wrong. The first piece of evidence comes from [Bea Stollnitz’s post about ListView](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=7): if one of the WPF developers explains how this might be done, it can’t be *that* wrong.

The other piece of evidence comes from this highly-voted question/answer: [MVVM madness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087743/mvvm-madness-commands). MVVM undoubtedly has its benefits, but sometimes the cost of following MVVM is so high that it’s just silly following through with it, especially in a small one-man application. Do you really want to [expose `IsSelected` and `IsExpanded` the way you’re supposed to](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode/)?

As a result, I felt justified to try and figure out how to expose the `TreeViewItem` corresponding to an item with less effort from the developer, under the assumption that they will never need the more advanced features that resulted in `TreeViewItem`s being this hard to access (like displaying the same ViewModels in multiple different controls... how often have you needed *that*!...)

I posted the result of this effort as [an answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9873104/33080).